# DateTime object not bound by its timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, dst

Is a `DateTime` object **not bound by its timestamp?** Or does **getTimestamp() has some kind of side-effect** when used **on DST change?**

**Details**
When setting the timestamp of a `DateTime` object  which is on `DST` (meaning the formatted time exists both before/after changing the clock) the returned timestamp differs from the set timestamp.

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.3 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2017 16:59:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

**Reproduce**
Consider the following `php` script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$date = new DateTime();
$set_timestamp = 1319932800;
$date->setTimestamp($set_timestamp);
$get_timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();

fwrite(STDERR, $set_timestamp . "\n");  // 1319932800
fwrite(STDERR, $get_timestamp . "\n");  // 1319936400 **(WHY IS THIS DIFFERENT?)**
```

**Why** are the printed values **not equal?**

Comment: @elbarto ofc you get the same. My problem relies explicitly around the DST handling of PHP about DateTime and for DST change for the given timestamp you need `Europe/Berlin` or similar. I can easily generate a timestamp for u (which will fail simirarly), if u give us your default timezone

Comment: Please check if it is already there https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&order_by=id&direction=DESC&limit=30&package_name%5B%5D=Date%2Ftime+related.

Comment: i think it is because the timezone doesn't apply to the static value $set_timestamp however the timezone does apply  $get_timestamp because its value was generated, thats what i think but either way its interesting will give it a try later my self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the unix timestamp is always in UTC, so it hasn't timezone and DST.

In other hand, the `DateTime` object stores **local time** only *(the "local" means what timezone is set in the `DateTime` instance)*.

Therefore you should set timezone to **+00:00** or **UTC** before you set a timestamp for avoid unnecessary time conversions and DST guessing.

You have two choices:

## 1. Set timestamp via constructor of `DateTime`

The constructor will overrides the default timezone and explicit set to **+00:00** when it got timestamp *(started with `@`)* in first parameter:

```
$set_timestamp = 1319932800;
$date = new DateTime('@' . $set_timestamp);

print($set_timestamp . "\n");
print($date->getTimestamp() . "\n");
```

*Info: in this case, the timezone parameter of constructor always will be overridden.*

## 2. Set timezone before call `setTimestamp()`

Call `setTimezone()` with `DateTimeZone('+00:00')` or `DateTimeZone('UTC')` timezone before you call `setTimestamp()`:

```
$set_timestamp = 1319932800;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimestamp($set_timestamp);

print($set_timestamp . "\n");
print($date->getTimestamp() . "\n");
```

## Notes

Of course, both of these cases the output will be:

```
1319932800
1319932800
```

---

The `date_default_timezone_set()` is unnecessary in these cases, because you don't want to do anything with local time.

However when you want to print the `$date` in human readable format *(so when you convert the unix timestamp to local time)* the timezone will be interesting again.

Comment: It may be worth to mention that class `DateTime` accept object of `DateTimeZone` in constructor as second parameter

Comment: Not working if timezone is changed back to `Europe/Berlin` before `getTimestamp()` https://repl.it/GwOF/0 =( Assuming @p1100i needs local timezone for other datetime calculations.

Answer (score 3):

`\DateTime` object doesn't keep timestamps but local time, and do conversions in [timestamp getter](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/7ba7a79039250842e6234c678fab408dec0191b9/ext/date/php_date.c#L3692) and [timestamp setter](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/7ba7a79039250842e6234c678fab408dec0191b9/ext/date/php_date.c#L3633).

It results with a side-effect once a year when DST is being switched off, since both timestamp ranges 1319932800..1319936400 and 1319936400..1319940000 resolve to the same local time:
https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1319936399&tz=Europe%2FBerlin
https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1319939999&tz=Europe%2FBerlin

Comment: I see, so basically, the `getter/setter` has side effects?

Comment: and also datetime object is not bound by its timestamp, rather its bounded by the local-time + timestamp together (in-a-weird php-kind-of-way)?

Comment: no, it's local-time+timezone only, which results with a spike of similar questions on SO twice a year.